# Can't get the uniqueness validation to work on an excel file I am uploading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

My Client model has two attributes: `:name` and `:address` (which is the web address for our client's website).  The point of the application is to see if a company is on the do not call list or a client before dialing them for prospecting purposes so the user can type in their web address and see if they can call or not.

I am using Ruby 2.3.1 and Rails 4.2.6

I have a uniqueness validation as well as a presence validation set for `:address`, but when I import an xlxs file with client addresses already in the database it still uploads them and just overwrites the original entries.  Meanwhile If I do not include an address, the presence validation does work. If I add companies one by one in the standard `Client#new` form the uniqueness validation does work. Just not with the excel.

I'm using the method found here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel?autoplay=true  and here: https://github.com/railscasts/396-importing-csv-and-excel/tree/master/store-with-validations

I'm using the client_import model and controller to try and make this work.

Here's my Client model: client.rb

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  #attr_accessible :name, :address

  validates :address, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false},
                      presence: true

  def self.search(q)
    where("name LIKE ?", "%#{q}%")
    where("address LIKE ?", "%#{q}%")
  end

  def self.import(file)
    spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
    header = spreadsheet.row(1)
    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
      row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
      client = find_by_address(row["address"]) || new
      client.attributes = row.to_hash #.slice(*accessible_attributes)
      client.save!
    end
  end

  def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
    case File.extname(file.original_filename)
      when ".csv" then Csv.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
      when ".xls" then Roo::Excel.new(file.path)
      when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path)
      else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
    end
  end
end
```

And my client_import Model : client_import.rb

```
class ClientImport
  # switch to ActiveModel::Model in Rails 4
  extend ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_accessor :file

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each { |name, value| send("#{name}=", value) }
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end

  def save
    if imported_clients.map(&:valid?).all?                          
      imported_clients.each(&:save!)
      true
    else
      imported_clients.each_with_index do |client, index|
        client.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
          errors.add :base, "Row #{index+2}: #{message}"
        end
      end
      false
    end
  end

  def imported_clients
    @imported_clients ||= load_imported_clients
  end

  def load_imported_clients
    spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet
    header = spreadsheet.row(1)
    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).map do |i|
      row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
      client = Client.find_by_address(row["address"]) || Client.new
      client.attributes = row.to_hash #.slice(Client.client_import_params)
      client
    end
  end

  def open_spreadsheet
    case File.extname(file.original_filename)
    when ".csv" then Csv.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
    when ".xls" then Roo::Excel.new(file.path)
    when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path)
    else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
    end
  end
end
```

My import_clients Controller: client_imports_controller.rb

```
class ClientImportsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @client_import = ClientImport.new
  end

  def create
    @client_import = ClientImport.new(params[:client_import])
    if @client_import.save
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Imported clients successfully."
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

The new.html.erb page the form for importing: Views/client_imports/newhtml.erb

```
<h1>Client Import</h1>

<p>A CSV or Excel file can be used to import records. The first row should be the column name. The following columns are allowed.</p>

<ul>
  <% Client.columns.each do |column| %>
    <% if column.name.in? ["address"] %>
      <li>
        <strong><%= column.name %></strong> -
        <%= column.type.to_s.titleize %> type
      </li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>

<p>If an <strong>id</strong> is supplied it will update the matching record instead of creating a new one.</p>

<%= form_for @client_import do |f| %>
  <% if @client_import.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@client_import.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this import from completing:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @client_import.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.file_field :file %>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons"><%= f.submit "Import" %></div>
<% end %>
```

And here's my routes file: routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :clients do
    collection do
      get 'search'
      post 'import'
    end
  end

  resources :client_imports

  root 'clients#search'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to change how the model looked for pre-existing records.  I had it set to look for similar addresses:

```
def load_imported_clients
    spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet
    header = spreadsheet.row(1)
    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).map do |i|
      row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
      client = Client.find_by_address(row["address"]) || Client.new
      client.attributes = row.to_hash #.slice(Client.client_import_params)
      client
    end
  end
```

But I needed it to search by ID like this

```
def load_imported_clients
  spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet
  header = spreadsheet.row(1)
  (2..spreadsheet.last_row).map do |i|
    row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
    client = Client.find_by_id(row["id"]) || Client.new
    client.attributes = row.to_hash #.slice(Client.client_import_params)
    client
  end
end
```